# Iterating over JSON nested object to create new object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following data:

```
  export interface BreakTimes {
    start? : string;
    end?   : string;
  }

  export interface WorkingPlanDays {
    start? : string;
    end?   : string;
    breaks? : BreakTimes[];
  }

  export interface WorkingPlan {
    [day : string]  : WorkingPlanDays;
  }

  const WORKING_PLAN_DATA: WorkingPlan = {
        "monday": null,
        "tuesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "wednesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "thursday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "friday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "20:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "14:30"
            }
          ]
        },
        "saturday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sunday": null
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is getting the break times in a new object like so:

```
  const ELEMENT_DATA: Breaks[] = [
    {day: 'Tuesday', start: '12:00', end: '12:30'},
    {day: 'Tuesday', start: '13:30', end: '13:50'},
    {day: 'Wednesday', start: '12:00', end: '12:30'},
    {day: 'Wednesday', start: '13:30', end: '13:50'},
    ...... etc....
  ];
```

What is the best way to do so?
I'm pretty new to javascript and typescript, getting a little confused on how to iterate over this object that has nested objects within.

If you have the answer could you please also explain how your code works to give me a better understanding?
Much appreciated guys!

Comment: best way for me is to use reduce. you can map each item to its break field. then merge it with the accumulator

Comment: for a start, there is no JSON - `WORKING_PLAN_DATA` is an `Object`

Comment: There isn't any JSON in this question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of a data structure. JSON can be stored in a file or represented as a string literal in the code. The value of variable `WORKING_PLAN_DATA` is an object literal whose keys are needlessly wrapped in double quotes, looking like a JSON. But it is not a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this snippet will be useful to get you started. Good luck.

(Edited to add version close to OP's desired output.)

See [for in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
const WorkingPlan = {
        "monday": null,
        "tuesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "wednesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "thursday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "friday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "20:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "14:30"
            }
          ]
        },
        "saturday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sunday": null
  }
  let day, breaks = new Array();
  for ( day in WorkingPlan ) {
    if ( WorkingPlan[day] && "breaks" in WorkingPlan[day] ) {
      breaks.push( {day: day, breaks: WorkingPlan[day].breaks});
    }
  }
  
  console.log(breaks);
  
  breaks =[];
  
for ( day in WorkingPlan ) {
    if ( WorkingPlan[day] && "breaks" in WorkingPlan[day] ) {
      WorkingPlan[day].breaks.forEach( v => {
      breaks.push( {day: day, start: v.start, end: v.end});
      });
    }
  }
    
  console.log(breaks);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const iterate = (obj) => {
const result = []
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key] !== null && obj[key].breaks) {
        obj[key].breaks.forEach(time=>{
      result.push({day:key, start: time.start,end:time.end})
      })
          
        }
    })
    return result
}

const response = iterate({
        "monday": null,
        "tuesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "wednesday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "thursday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:30",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "friday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "20:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "14:30"
            }
          ]
        },
        "saturday": {
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "17:00",
          "breaks": [
            {
              "start": "12:00",
              "end": "12:30"
            },
            {
              "start": "13:30",
              "end": "13:50"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sunday": null
  })
  
  console.log(response)
```

You can try this solution